# Why is my Spring webFilter blocking Cors?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, session, filter, cors

I've set up an Angular client that sends requests to a Spring server.  I had overcome the CORS blocking a while ago and all requests went through fine.  Until I added a @webFilter on the spring side, and now I get the CORS error, allowing GET requests but none other.
If I put the webFilter in a comment, the code works fine (but doesn't check for login).

I added a restConfig class on the server side that allows all methods from my client address (localhost:4200).
Even when I put the @CrossOrigin per controller (even on the filter file) it doesn't change the affect.
I added withCredentials on both Angular side (per request) and server side (in the restConfig class and in the @CrossOrigin annotation.) 
I added the session dependency in pom.xml.

I also have an interceptor on the Angular side but this was happening before I added the interceptor.

When I try to delete, for example, the console writes an error: 
 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem/sec/admin/removecompany/3 
with a 401 error (even though I'm logged in) and elaborates: 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem/sec/admin/removecompany/3' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

As noted, get requests (which return 200) pass fine.

On inspecting the request sent, these are the headers that show in delete:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem/sec/admin/removecompany/3
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 13:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/admin/removecompany
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors <--I wonder if this line needs to be changed.
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36

If it has to do with headers being changed, I would need specific instructions how to add headers.

This is the webfilter:

```java
//Overcoming CORS while allowing cookies
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true",
methods= {RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.TRACE})
@WebFilter("/sec/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            httpResponse.sendError(401, "You are not logged in.");

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code of one of my restControllers:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("sec/admin")
//For overcoming CORS while allowing cookies
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true") 

public class AdminWebService {

    @Autowired
    AdminService adminService;

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    //GET method - works fine
@RequestMapping(path = "companies") 
    public List<Company> findAllCompanies() {
        return adminService.getAllCompanies();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "newcompany")//CORS ERROR
    public Company createCompany(@RequestBody Company company) throws IncompatibleInputException {
        return adminService.createCompany(company);
    }


        @PutMapping(path = "updatecompany/{id}") //CORS ERROR
    public void updateCompany(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Company company)
            throws IncompatibleInputException, ObjectNotFoundException {
        adminService.updateCompany(company, id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "removecompany/{id}")//CORS ERROR
    public boolean deleteCompany(@PathVariable long id) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        adminService.removeCompany(id);
        return true;
    }
```

This is the restConfig class which allows CORS through for the entire web app (so @CrossOrigin isn't really necessary, from what I understand.):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
public class RestConfig{

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE")
                .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

This is Angular side - a request being sent:

```js
 public updateCompany(companyToUpdate: Company) {
        this.httpClient.put<Company>(`${this.baseUrl}updatecompany/${companyToUpdate.id}`, companyToUpdate, { withCredentials: true })
            .subscribe(() => alert(`Company ${companyToUpdate.id} has been successfully updated.`), err => alert("We could not update this company.  " + err.error.messages));
    }

    deleteCompany(id: number) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete company of id ' + id + '?')) { //user must confirm his intention to delete
            this.httpClient.delete(`${this.baseUrl}removecompany/${id}`, { withCredentials: true })
                .subscribe(res => {
                    alert(`Company ${id} deleted successfully.`);
                    this.getAllCompanies();//update table
                }, err => {
                    alert("Unable to delete. " + err.error.messages);
                    this.getAllCompanies(); //Update dropdown with existing companies.
                }
                );
        } else {
            // Do nothing.  Giving user a chance to regret it.
        }
    }
```

This is the interceptor on the Angular side - although I don't think this is the problem since the requests get blocked by CORS before they are even sent to the server.

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
            // Checking if it is an Authentication Error (401)
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this.router.navigate([`/login`]);
                alert('You are not logged in.  Log in first.');
                return throwError(error);
            }
            // If it is not an authentication error, just throw it
            return throwError(error);
        }));
    }
}
```

I expect all requests to go through smoothly, not just GET.  (If a user is not logged in, it should filter him and send a 401 and only then will the Angular interceptor block him.)  and to stop giving me the CORS error when sending requests.

Comment: What is the error in browser console??

Comment: @gnanajeyam95  This is the text in the console: (to provide a sample browser text I tried to use a delete request to remove a company)
removecompany:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem/sec/admin/removecompany/5' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I stumbled upon the answer.  This has to do with the preflight request that is sent to the server when dealing with HTTP requests that are non-simple (like put, or post in some cases).
The client's preflight request was sent with the 'OPTIONS' method which apparently does not have the session-id attached to it.  This request was always met with the LoginFilter which conditioned:

```
    if (session == null) {
    httpResponse.sendError(401, "You are not logged in.");
    }
```

I solved this by expanding the 'if' clause to:

```
    if (session == null&&(!"OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getMethod())))  {
    httpResponse.sendError(401, "You are not logged in.");
    }
```

And if this helps anyone, I also managed the entire CORS issue with a CorsFilter that also takes care of the 'Options' method and returns a 200 OK response:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Value("${cors.origin}")
    private String preDefinedCorsOrigin;

    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest && res instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

            // Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", preDefinedCorsOrigin);
            response.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");

            // Access-Control-Max-Age
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

            // Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            // Access-Control-Allow-Methods
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type, Accept");

            if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across this issue in my Spring cloud API gateway.
Cors Bean does do any difference. So I added my config in application.yml file.

```
spring:
   cloud:    
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowed-origins: "*"
            allowed-methods: "*"
            allowed-headers: "*"
            allow-credentials: true
```

Above I used `default-filters` to remove multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. Consider a scenario, if your API gateway and downstream services setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` therefore your response header from server filled with multiple response headers browser wont allow.

To remove multiple response headers we are using this

```
 - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
```